# google sheets IF AND statements not working

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-apps, r-googlesheets

Hi im trying to execute a AND IF statement inside an existing IF statement but its not reading the value from cell O:O

Here is the code - screenshot of the sheet included

Any ideas on what im doing wrong

=Arrayformula(IF(ROW(G:G)=1,"Status",IF(A:A="","",IF(E:E="","In Progress",IF(E:E<5000,"Completed",(if(AND(E:E>=5000,O:O="Accept"),"Completed","")))))))

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND doesn't work in an array. See if this (slightly amended) formula works for you ?

```
=Arrayformula(IF(ROW(G:G)=1,"Status",IF(A:A="","",IF(E:E="","In Progress",IF(E:E<5000,"Completed",if( (E:E>=5000)*(O:O="Accept"),"Completed",""))))))
```